# set of meromorphic function $K(U)$ needs not to be a field if $U$ is not connect?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $K(U)$ be the set of meromorphic function on $U\subset \Bbb{C}^n$, which is defined as a function that locally can be written as fraction of two holomorphic function and agree on their intersection.

we can define the ring structure on it, if $U$ is connected, then we claim $K(U)$ is a field. is there some example that when $U$ is not connected , $K(U)$ is not field? (I believe that this condition is needed since $K(U)$ is a field only for irreducible varieties.)

maybe I have a simple example, but I am not sure if my understanding is correct. Just pick $U$ be disjoint union of two open subsets in $\Bbb{C}$ and set $f = 1$ on $U_1$ and $f= 0$ on $U_2$. then it's meromorphic since the gluing condition is vacuous. But it's not invertible on $U_2$, therefore $K(U)$ is not a field. The reason that this can not happen on the connected $U$ is that there if $f_i/g_i$ with $f_i = 0$ on a local piece will propagate to the whole $U$(via the chain of the open subsets(which use to define the local representation of $f$ )

Comment: Your example works.